# different between user_id and user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, userid

I understand the difference between user and user_id (one references a use by their id), but i don't get understand why a tutorial I am following for integration testing in rails uses :user_id for testing the login and redirect and :user for testing the logout and redirect.

Here's the code for both:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserStoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

test "should login user and redirect" do
  get login_path

  assert_response :success
  assert_template 'new'

  post session_path, email: 'myemail@email.com', password: 
  'secret'

  assert_response :redirect
  assert_redirected_to root_path

  follow_redirect! 

  assert_response :success
  assert_template 'index'
  assert session[:user_id]
end

test "should logout user and redirect" do 
  get logout_path

  assert_response :redirect
  assert_redirected_to root_path
  assert_nil session[:user]

  follow_redirect!

  assert_template 'index'
end
end
```

Comment: Looks like a typo, they are different. That last test should always pass (the `assert_nil session[:user]` anyways) because you aren't setting `session[:user]`.

Comment: Looks like a typo. `assert_nil session[:user]` will pass if the login process is setting the :user_id.

Comment: Okay so for the login test, assert session[:user] should work too? And is that preferable to doing assert session[:user_id]?

Comment: No, I think the other way around. Depends on what the login process is setting.

Comment: put assert `session[:user]` in the `should login user and redirect` test. Is it failing? then you should change `session[:user]` to `session[:user_id]` in the `should logout user and redirect`